# Can Silicon hinder the precipitation of AgCl?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, metal

In my lab, I am having trouble with getting correct silver percentages.

For example, let's say a 99.99% silver sample. Digested in 10 mL of a 30% HNO3, fill up to 100 mL with DI, then concentrated (12M) HCl is added to precipitate the silver (around 10 - 15 drops of HCl around 1.50-2 mL). I was wondering if silicon can hinder the precipitation of silver because I recently had some contamination of silicon in my nitric acid and have not been able to get consistent 99.99% on this alloy.

Comment: Is the supposed accuracy that great?

Comment: Yes the accuracy of that alloy is 4 9's. Pure silver alloy

Comment: I mean the accuracy of the method to determine 99.99% Ag. What is the standard deviation of the measurement average or the respective confidence intervals?

Comment: Well the alloys measurement average is 99.99-100%. Most time I assay this alloy it usually comes out to around 99.97%. The accuracy of the method is 100% its just a simple gravimetric analysis.

Comment: Matt - RE: *The accuracy of the method is 100% its just a simple gravimetric analysis. * The method isn't 100% according to your information. You state that the sample is 99.99% Ag yet you average 99.97%. so you have a low bias which I would expect from a good gravimetric analysis. //  If you know you have silicon in the nitric acid then use that acid for something else and get a better grade of nitric acid. // Are you following some standard procedure?

Comment: The method of gravimetric analysis to my knowledge has a 100% accuracy. Not talking about my specific method, I do not know the measured accuracy of my procedure. My lab buys the highest grade nitric acid there is. I am following a standard procedure.

Comment: @Matt, "The method of gravimetric analysis to my knowledge has a 100% accuracy." In the real world, *nothing* has 100% accuracy. There is always some loss, or adsorption or contamination, or variability of atomic mass. Even were one to count atoms, there could be loss.

Comment: Okay I understand that nothing has 100% accuracy but no one has answered my question. Can the presence of silicon hinder the precipitation of silver chloride?

Comment: I can, as multiple other things that were not eliminated.

Answer (score 4):

Gravimetric and coulometric methods are among the most accurate techniques known to analytical chemists despite their presence in dated textbooks. However, it's important to remember that in order to obtain highly precise results—such as when measuring atomic weights or ultrapure substances like the one you have—one must exercise high level of caution!

Dissolved silica should not interfere in the precipitation of silver chloride. If you are concerned about silicon, it is an insoluble solid. You might be concerned about dissolved silicon...if any. It may bias the results upon evaporation towards the higher side (just a conjecture). However, classical gravimetry books such as Hildebrand's Applied Inorganic Analysis, do suggest that silver cannot be accurately analyzed in the presence of silicate rocks. I think it will be rare to have the expertise and patience today to reach that level of accuracy as was done by the 19th century chemist with silver chloride precipitations/determination by Theodore W. Richards (Nobel Laureate).

Many questions for the apparently lower results for not getting 99.99 % purity or higher silver content from an ultrapure starting material.

1. Is your balance calibrated to the highest grade weights traceable to some standard organization?
2. Are you doing buoyancy corrections during weighing?
3. What is the solubility of silver chloride in that solution?
4. Are you using the right porosity filter for filtration
5. Is the method a standard method from a reputable organization?

In short if you are getting 99.97% for something labeled as 99.99%, then your analytical skills are highly commendable.

Comment: I assume dissolved silicate could  cause trapping part of Ag+ or AgCl in colloid, lost for precipitation.